# The dim() function's convention to insert parameters

Tags: r

This line is really difficult for me who is java programmer to understand. I think ' <-' ,the operator , is a assign operator. But how could I understand the internal sub-processes. c(5,4) makes vectors with two values and then how does this value to deliver to the dim function's input? This convention is not good for me to be familiar with this.

```
dim(m) <- c(5,4)  # Dimensions set to 5 & 4, so m is now a 5x4 matrix
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is often referred to as "syntactic sugar".

R's objects are theoretically immutable. Doing something like:

```
 dim(m) = c(4,5)
```

looks like it is changing `m`, but in reality the syntax tree is written to be like:

```
m = D(m, c(4,5))
```

where `D` is a function that constructs a matrix from another matrix and a new set of dimensions. The previous `m` is now probably up for garbage collection, and the name `m` now points to the re-dimensioned matrix.

Syntactic sugar like this is used in R in most places where objects seem to mutate, such as `a[1]=2`, which is expressed in the syntax tree as `a = B(a,1,2)`, where `B` is a constructor function that creates a vector from the original `a` but with the first value set to two.

Note: These assignment functions, `D` and `B` in the above examples are actually named `dim<-` and `[<-` in R, I called the `D` and `B` for clarity because function names with `<-` look a bit weird but are perfectly acceptable identifiers in R

Comment: While what you say is generally true for every `*<-` function, the `[<-` function is handled differently (at least in recent R versions) and might actually change the object *by reference*. Try for instance `require(data.table);a<-1:10;address(a);a[7L]<-11L;address(a)` and often the address will be the same before and after the replacement.

Comment: @nicola in [<-   what [ does mean?

Comment: And I tried the instance. But i tried many times. but all was the same

Comment: In fact many built-in function avoid copying objects where possible to do so while still maintaining the illusion that a copy is made. In @nicola example, the object bound to "a" is not bound to anything else, so it can be safely changed in-place (nobody will notice - except the "data.table::address" function that is something that should never be used for anything but low-level debugging).

Answer (score 1):

When you do `dim(m) <- *`, you're actually calling a *different* function to set the dimensions of `m`. This function is `dim<-`. It's equivalent to the following:

```
m <- `dim<-`(m, c(5, 4))
```

So what happens is that a new matrix is returned with the dimensions you specified. The R parser handles the task of turning your original syntax into a call to `dim<-`.

The same thing happens with other assignment operations like `names(*) <-`, `class(*) <-`, and so on. It also happens when you assign to subsets, like `m[a, b] <-`: in this case the function is `[<-`.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct `<-` is an assignment operator (in almost all circumstances, it's the same as the `=` operator).

When you run

```
dim(m) <- c(5, 4)
```

You are actually calling the function

```
dim<-
```

This function even has a help page `?dim<-`. So

```
dim(m) <- c(5, 4)
```

Is equivalent to

```
m <- `dim<-`(m, c(5, 2))
```

This is very common in R:

```
# Vectors
x[1] = 10
## Data frames
df[1, 2] = 50
```

Comment: so.. you mean the operator is not only assign the value to the value in the left but also assign the parameters to the function in the left?

Comment: If I understand your comment, yes